# Python Script to Calculate Historical S&P 500 Returns over Requested Time Span

Tags: python, performance

I have a Python script that calculates the historical S&P 500 returns from a starting balance and annual contribution. The script also outputs interesting statistics (mean/min/max/stddev/confidence intervals) related to the historical returns. I'm seeking feedback on how the code could be refactored more efficiently.

sp500_time_machine.py

```
import os, sys, time
import datetime
import argparse
import statistics
import math
from sp500_data import growth

MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12
FIRST_YEAR = 1928 # This is the first year of data from the dataset

# Given an initial investment, an annual contribution and a span in years, show how the investment would mature 
# based on historical trends of the S&P 500
def sp500_time_machine(starting_balance, span, annual_contribution):
    realized_gain_list = []
    average_gain = 0
    current_year = datetime.date.today().year # Grab this from the OS
    total_spans = (current_year - FIRST_YEAR - span) + 1

    # Adjust the starting year for each span
    for base_year in range(total_spans):
        realized_gains = starting_balance
        # Loop through each span, month by month
        for month in range(span * MONTHS_PER_YEAR):
            realized_gains = (realized_gains + (annual_contribution / MONTHS_PER_YEAR)) * (1 + growth[month + base_year] / 100)

        # Store each realized gain over the requested span in a list for later processing
        realized_gain_list.append(realized_gains)
        print("S&P realized gains plus principle from %s to %s for %s starting balance = %s" % ((FIRST_YEAR + base_year), (FIRST_YEAR + base_year + span), f'{starting_balance:,}', f'{int(realized_gains):,}'))
        average_gain = average_gain + realized_gains

    # Display the average, minimum and maximum gain over the requested time span
    mean = int(average_gain / total_spans)
    print("Average %s year realized gains plus principle over %d years is %s" % (span, total_spans, f'{mean:,}'))

    # Calculate the standard deviation
    std_dev = statistics.stdev(realized_gain_list)
    print("Standard Deviation = %s" % f'{int(std_dev):,}')

    # Determine the 99% confidence interval
    #
    # Stock market returns are not normally distributed, so this is a simplification of actual real-world data
    # https://klementoninvesting.substack.com/p/the-distribution-of-stock-market
    # 
    # z-score values are based on normal distributions
    # The value of 1.96 is based on the fact that 95% of the area of a normal distribution is within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean
    # Likewise, 2.58 standard deviations contain 99% of the area of a normal distribution
    # 90% confidence z-value = 1.65
    # 95% confidence z-value = 1.96
    # 99% confidence z-value = 2.58
    upper_interval = mean + 2.58 * (std_dev / math.sqrt(total_spans))
    print("99%% Confidence Interval (Upper) = %s" % f'{int(upper_interval):,}')

    lower_interval = mean - 2.58 * (std_dev / math.sqrt(total_spans))
    print("99%% Confidence Interval (Lower) = %s" % f'{int(lower_interval):,}')

    # Find the min/max values
    min_gain = min(realized_gain_list)
    min_gain_index = realized_gain_list.index(min_gain)
    print("Minimum realized gain plus principle over %d years occurred from %s to %s with a final balance of %s" % 
        (span, min_gain_index + FIRST_YEAR, min_gain_index + FIRST_YEAR + span, f'{int(min_gain):,}'))

    max_gain = max(realized_gain_list)
    man_gain_index = realized_gain_list.index(max_gain)
    print("Maximum realized gain plus principle over %d years occurred from %s to %s with a final balance of %s" % 
        (span, man_gain_index + FIRST_YEAR, man_gain_index + FIRST_YEAR + span, f'{int(max_gain):,}'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--span", help="The number of consecutive years (span) to iterate over")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--principle", help="The initial investment amount")
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--annual", help="The annual contribution amount")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    sp500_time_machine(int(args.principle), int(args.span), int(args.annual))
```

sp500_data.py

```
# Monthly growth data taken from https://www.officialdata.org/us/stocks/s-p-500/ and based upon http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm
# This data contains reinvested dividends
# This data does NOT adjust for inflation!
growth = [-0.83, 5.75, 6.66, 3.44, -4.57, 1.09, 3.59, 7.37, 2.36, 7.08, 0.70, 7.69, 0.81, 2.05, -0.30, 1.80, 2.20, 9.20, 5.96, 4.24, -10.32, -26.19, 4.37, 1.83, 6.64, 4.12, 6.69, -5.65, -9.77, -1.76, -0.90, 0.34, -13.37, -6.80, -6.19, 3.56, 8.14, 2.38, -9.08, -9.16, -2.68, 3.86, -2.49, -14.37, -12.75, 2.05, -18.10, -0.85, -0.05, 1.14, -23.22, -11.31, -12.39, 6.18, 51.35, 10.37, -13.22, -0.34, -2.64, 4.57, -11.27, 0.33, 11.24, 29.32, 17.58, 8.46, -4.64, -0.48, -9.38, 2.80, 2.32, 6.08, 7.75, -4.80, 2.02, -9.83, 1.70, -4.36, -3.51, -2.01, 1.21, 3.21, 1.06, 0.40, -2.62, -5.93, 7.94, 8.27, 4.17, 5.60, 7.10, 2.43, 2.99, 9.71, 0.29, 5.82, 6.03, 2.41, 0.41, -5.02, 4.57, 6.23, 2.30, 1.44, 5.55, 3.10, -1.40, 3.46, 3.30, 0.23, -5.62, -4.09, -3.34, 6.39, 1.44, -13.76, -14.10, -8.27, -1.02, 3.24, -1.80, -6.02, -3.44, 1.56, 2.93, 20.49, 1.06, -4.08, 11.62, 0.47, -2.55, -1.16, -0.46, 0.27, -12.24, 4.10, 2.17, 2.84, -1.07, 11.06, 1.38, -1.41, -1.97, -0.15, -0.23, -0.15, 1.42, -13.34, -8.09, 3.87, 2.65, 4.76, 1.47, 2.85, -3.59, 0.72, -5.72, 1.18, -2.55, -1.59, 4.11, 5.71, 0.08, 0.86, -3.43, -4.08, -5.88, 2.62, -2.48, -4.76, -3.45, 1.87, 5.75, 4.38, 0.05, 1.66, 7.97, 2.15, 1.06, 6.50, 6.43, 4.01, 3.79, 4.36, 2.18, 2.47, -4.54, 2.55, -0.50, -4.21, 1.77, 3.67, -0.24, 3.24, -1.31, 2.20, 5.14, 3.02, -1.06, -1.23, 2.88, -0.28, 2.60, 3.38, 3.73, 0.31, 2.90, 4.16, 2.19, -1.70, 0.71, 7.18, 4.51, 3.61, 2.02, 4.30, 0.59, -2.68, 6.77, 0.52, -0.34, -2.55, -1.62, -14.42, -1.87, -0.01, 3.39, 0.92, 4.27, -3.67, -3.30, -1.36, 3.92, 6.69, -1.56, -2.17, 3.03, -0.73, -1.12, -0.86, -4.45, 1.92, 8.19, 5.33, 4.59, -1.96, -2.49, -0.68, 3.19, -5.10, -0.16, 1.63, -3.33, 1.49, 0.41, -0.18, -4.91, 6.26, 4.17, 1.87, 3.14, 1.95, 3.24, 2.63, 2.52, 1.38, 3.39, 3.91, 2.16, -6.72, 6.64, 4.11, 4.72, 0.38, 0.19, 8.01, 4.31, -1.11, 1.93, 0.63, -1.15, 2.37, 4.97, 3.14, 0.03, -2.25, 3.61, 3.83, -1.33, 0.75, 0.20, 0.46, 3.24, 3.37, 0.88, -1.11, -1.61, 3.67, 4.51, 0.99, -0.77, 0.96, -4.47, 1.00, -3.11, 1.91, 0.90, -4.11, 3.52, 2.71, 1.84, 3.02, 2.68, 2.58, 4.45, 4.42, 1.22, 4.46, 2.39, 2.74, 2.71, 4.30, 4.95, 2.17, 3.70, -0.44, 3.81, -0.08, 6.15, 7.64, -0.30, 4.82, -4.72, 7.07, 1.24, -2.39, 0.95, 7.21, 1.48, -2.84, -0.26, 5.75, -0.28, -3.09, -0.95, -0.71, 1.81, -1.86, -4.00, 1.62, 2.64, 4.16, 1.95, 2.32, -5.21, -3.74, -5.90, -1.80, 0.32, 2.33, 0.70, 2.42, 0.90, 3.56, 2.74, 3.07, 4.05, 2.94, 4.36, 3.33, 2.16, 4.25, -1.27, 2.81, 1.94, 1.77, -0.61, 4.23, -0.32, -3.70, 0.18, 0.67, 3.46, -1.49, -3.61, -1.08, 1.58, -0.62, 3.99, -2.20, 1.49, -2.72, -1.67, 3.54, 2.69, 5.43, 4.37, 3.40, 2.92, 1.26, -1.08, -0.03, 3.84, -0.54, 1.34, 4.77, 1.16, -3.49, 1.91, 0.34, -2.94, -7.19, -11.41, 2.72, 3.02, -0.59, -2.86, 7.20, 4.62, 4.15, 1.60, -0.11, 4.98, 2.27, 0.22, -1.22, 3.03, 2.89, 0.50, -0.31, 2.39, 3.33, 1.48, 2.07, 1.69, 1.22, -0.35, 3.96, -1.23, 1.97, 1.97, 0.94, -1.49, 2.82, 0.98, 0.34, 1.56, 1.73, -4.51, 0.10, 2.12, 3.60, 2.50, 1.08, -0.21, 1.98, -0.43, -3.86, 3.32, -5.01, -0.56, 0.02, -5.77, -3.22, -0.56, 5.32, 0.72, 4.13, 3.73, 2.63, 1.99, 2.06, -0.99, 1.99, 1.85, 1.65, 0.10, -2.88, 3.11, -0.02, -4.26, -1.56, 7.66, 2.56, 2.94, 0.05, -1.93, 3.51, 2.72, 1.79, 1.29, -3.99, -0.24, -1.91, 2.27, 3.51, -4.97, -4.21, -0.28, 0.63, 1.35, 1.00, -5.03, -0.59, -3.20, 2.01, -2.75, -11.20, -0.27, 0.52, 3.26, 6.32, 2.49, 0.21, 7.16, 4.11, 4.15, 2.83, 3.67, -1.11, -1.60, -0.46, -1.52, 2.49, -1.86, -4.37, 7.16, 4.42, 2.09, 2.62, 1.26, -0.78, 0.52, -0.50, 3.78, -1.21, 0.42, 5.25, 2.31, 0.99, -3.33, -1.35, -1.63, -2.57, -1.99, 1.21, -1.64, 2.00, 4.24, -6.85, -6.81, 1.70, -2.47, 4.57, -4.82, -2.71, 0.46, -11.35, -3.76, -10.01, 2.38, 3.74, -6.09, 8.63, 10.81, 4.97, 1.49, 6.71, 2.89, 0.43, -7.00, -0.85, 4.97, 2.04, -1.18, 9.55, 4.18, 0.80, 1.10, -0.38, 0.90, 2.67, -0.56, 2.44, -3.11, -0.37, 3.79, -0.54, -2.37, -0.05, -1.19, 0.06, 0.90, 1.28, -2.08, -1.18, -2.20, 0.98, -0.08, -3.39, -0.97, 0.27, 4.83, 5.50, 0.67, -0.06, 7.33, 0.40, -2.77, -5.44, 1.92, 4.19, -1.06, 2.34, 2.43, -1.89, 2.42, 1.42, 5.01, 1.54, -3.35, -0.32, 4.40, 3.31, 4.40, -8.78, -1.16, 5.04, 6.86, 4.97, 3.50, 2.84, 3.32, 4.61, -1.24, 0.01, -3.07, 4.14, 1.29, -1.62, 0.86, -2.02, 0.80, -8.30, 1.73, 3.04, 1.18, -4.80, -1.91, -2.74, 5.47, 0.57, -5.27, 0.24, 0.79, 12.10, 8.88, 4.50, 1.36, 3.93, 2.13, 3.87, 4.20, 4.42, 1.75, 0.71, -2.41, 3.31, 0.65, -1.14, -0.13, 1.58, -5.11, 0.44, 0.51, -0.25, -1.85, -0.91, 9.21, 1.41, -0.41, 1.29, -0.71, 4.70, 5.79, -0.48, 1.02, 2.74, 2.51, 2.25, -1.85, -1.88, 1.50, 6.42, 5.29, 0.75, 5.70, 6.18, 2.74, 0.49, 3.13, -1.80, 2.28, -2.46, -0.09, 3.53, 1.71, 6.67, 6.46, 4.38, -0.86, 0.17, 4.50, 3.12, 6.45, -3.03, -11.85, -12.30, -1.33, 4.25, 3.33, 3.23, -0.89, -2.19, 6.00, -0.31, -1.72, 1.93, 3.80, -2.02, 2.33, 3.51, 3.30, -0.16, 3.56, 4.12, 3.39, 2.80, 4.69, 0.46, 0.29, -1.81, 2.74, -2.21, -2.53, 2.71, 0.20, 3.85, 3.17, 0.17, -7.86, -4.34, -2.32, 2.98, 4.59, -0.69, 11.61, 3.04, 2.26, -0.18, 0.35, 0.78, 2.68, -0.30, 0.18, 0.02, 0.94, 7.36, -0.60, -1.01, 0.26, 2.07, -1.33, 1.91, 0.94, 0.38, -1.18, 2.76, 3.27, 0.14, 1.72, 2.15, -1.34, 0.72, 0.87, 0.06, 1.76, 1.35, 1.24, 0.01, 0.89, 1.74, -0.08, -1.42, -3.35, 1.06, 1.11, -0.52, 3.08, 0.82, -0.44, -0.37, -1.03, 2.45, 3.82, 2.56, 3.22, 3.35, 3.18, 3.55, 0.51, 3.72, 0.91, 2.36, 3.39, 0.16, 5.90, -0.20, 0.20, 2.35, 1.28, -3.48, 3.08, 2.02, 4.12, 5.05, 1.20, 3.26, 4.36, -0.62, -3.41, 9.22, 5.34, 5.74, 0.35, 1.19, 1.65, -1.15, 2.63, 0.24, 6.40, 5.31, 3.41, -0.22, 0.12, 4.47, -6.97, -4.90, 1.29, 10.97, 4.10, 5.05, -0.07, 2.92, 4.25, -0.10, -0.61, 4.52, -3.77, -0.60, -1.27, 7.11, 2.81, -0.12, -2.48, 3.94, 1.42, -2.84, 3.16, 0.85, 0.94, -1.08, -5.21, -0.77, -3.32, 0.46, -2.14, -9.08, 0.45, 6.88, -2.39, -2.66, -2.05, -11.25, 3.18, 5.05, 1.47, -0.30, -3.35, 4.95, -3.51, -2.82, -5.92, -10.76, 1.14, -4.76, -1.37, 6.63, -1.04, -0.22, -6.41, 1.31, 5.29, 5.31, 5.70, 0.60, -0.17, 3.16, 2.03, 1.21, 3.06, 4.93, 1.09, -1.57, 0.97, -2.56, 2.86, -2.24, -1.39, 2.78, 0.10, 4.77, 2.73, -1.35, 1.68, -0.26, -2.41, 1.34, 2.18, 1.81, 0.31, 0.28, -2.62, 3.96, 2.14, 1.47, -0.02, 1.49, 0.80, -0.79, -2.71, 0.72, 2.29, 2.53, 3.62, 2.00, 2.15, 0.69, 1.60, -2.47, 4.18, 3.39, 0.34, 0.57, -4.20, 3.07, 2.99, -4.81, 1.24, -6.64, -1.56, -2.63, 4.24, 2.56, -4.25, -6.08, 2.11, -4.85, -20.19, -8.61, -0.35, -1.10, -6.70, -5.69, 12.32, 6.66, 2.87, 1.28, 8.12, 3.65, 2.40, 2.09, 2.23, 1.36, -2.90, 5.94, 4.09, -5.88, -3.54, -0.16, 0.86, 3.37, 4.58, 2.49, 3.71, 3.46, 3.15, -1.11, 2.22, 0.66, -3.66, 3.10, -10.40, -0.79, 3.02, 1.77, 1.55, 4.78, 4.16, 2.88, -0.04, -3.09, -1.15, 2.92, 3.39, 3.02, -0.22, -2.84, 2.18, 4.27, 2.33, 2.72, 1.45, 4.57, -1.12, 3.25, 0.25, 1.19, 2.12, 3.86, 1.52, 0.97, -0.13, 2.72, 0.20, 1.53, 3.20, 1.50, -0.43, 1.78, -2.65, 5.71, 0.63, -1.11, 2.83, 0.06, 0.88, 0.98, -0.44, -0.08, -2.42, -4.51, 4.32, 2.93, -1.10, -6.42, -0.55, 6.36, 2.83, -0.30, 1.07, 3.30, 1.20, -0.44, -0.51, 1.20, 3.95, 1.44, 2.58, 1.75, -0.15, 1.69, 1.78, 0.99, 0.25, 1.65, 2.73, 1.59, 2.88, 4.86, -2.89, 0.06, -1.66, 1.96, 2.11, 1.58, 2.45, 1.68, -3.85, -2.08, -5.56, 1.74, 5.83, 1.95, 3.72, -1.53, 1.40, 3.83, -3.13, 3.09, 0.01, 4.43, 2.47, 3.35, 0.12, -18.92, 4.32, 5.89, 6.51, 3.48, 5.89, -0.63, 1.73, 3.95, 4.26, 2.80, 2.49, 0.82, 6.02, 0.76, 1.81, 3.07, 2.19, -0.08, 0.45, 4.74, 0.27, -2.05, -2.90, -0.89, 0.12, -7.87, -3.37, 0.46, 6.45, -7.28, -3.09, 5.29, 0.01, 1.38, 3.15, -2.59, 4.00, 0.60, 4.80, 2.54]
```

Example usage:
`python3 sp500_time_machine.py -s20 -p100000 -a0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## lint

minor [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) nit:
It would be useful to run
[isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort) on this.

---

## docstrings where appropriate

```
# Given an initial investment ...
```

This is a helpful comment, and I thank you for it.

It would be more helpful as a """docstring""".

---

## returning numeric results

```
def sp500_time_machine(starting_balance, span, annual_contribution):
```

This is an OK signature.
Consider adding `float`, `int`, `float` type hints to it.

`span` has units of years,
but that only becomes apparent upon reading the code.
We could introduce it a little more clearly.

If we *did* add type hinting, the signature would end with

```
def ... ) -> None:
```

which makes me sad.
It fits with the verb "show" in the introductory comment.

At fifty-ish lines this function is not *too* long.
But it does do more than
[one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Consider breaking out the initial loop as a helper function,
which returns a list of results.

More generally, consider making the computation of figures
separate from the display of figures.
This aids composition, and allows a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to verify specific calculations.

---

## globals and testability

```
    current_year = datetime.date.today().year
```

This is nice enough, but it relies on a global variable (clock).
It would be much nicer if we saw `def ... , current_year=None):`
in the signature, which defaults to current year:

```
    current_year = current_year or datetime.date.today().year
```

That way a unit test could specify e.g. `2022`
to "freeze" an historic result in time.
And the test would continue pass in 2024, 2025, and following years.

---

## units, & parallel structure to names

The meaning of this manifest constant is very clear:

```
FIRST_YEAR = 1928
```

This *seems* to be a similar quantity, but it is zero-origin:

```
    for base_year in range(total_spans):
```

Ultimately it combines with
`for month in range(span * MONTHS_PER_YEAR)`
to form an anonymous `month + base_year` index.

Going back and forth on the units is a bit jarring.
Consider incrementing a `datetime.date`
(or `datetime.datetime`) in the loop.
Consider breaking out that `growth[]`
de-reference so a helper function "knows"
how to turn a point-in-time into
the correct array index.

```
        # Store each realized gain over the requested span in a list for later processing
```

Elide the obvious comment -- the code eloquently said that already.

```
        realized_gain_list.append(realized_gains)
```

Consider switching to a `dict` so the year is apparent:
`realized_gain[FIRST_YEAR + base_year] = realized_gains`.
The idea is to produce a results datastructure
which a maintenance engineer could not possibly misinterpret.

```
    ... starting balance = %s" % ...
```

Outputting an explicit `$` dollar sign wouldn't hurt.
Consider using an
[f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
rather than the `%` percent operator.

---

## extract helper

```
    # Display the average, ...
```

To keep computation and display separate,
consider breaking out this section into a helper function.

Thank you for the Klement citation
and the reminder of Gaussian facts,
so the magic numbers are well-explained.

---

## wrangling inputs

Nice arg parser.
Aha! `"--span", help="The number of consecutive years (span) ...` --
that's what I'd been looking for, perfect.

```
    ... int(args.principle), int(args.span), int(args.annual)
```

Consider asking
[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)
to call `int()` for you,
by specifying `type=int`.

---

## docstrings on data

In `sp500_data.py`,
thank you for the pair of URL citations,
and for the "not in constant dollars!" warning.

These comments would work nicely as a """docstring"""
on the `growth` vector.
Then a maintenance engineer could import it and use
`help(growth)` to better understand how to correctly
interpret those figures.

The list of pasted numbers is straightforward,
and it's fine that we wind up with a very long line.
It's too bad that we don't see code or comments
explaining how that list was downloaded / cleaned / computed,
in case we want to reproduce results or incorporate
recent data a few years from now.

---

This function achieves its design goals.
It would benefit from unit tests,
and from pushing `print()` statements
into separate helpers.

I would be willing to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on this codebase.

Comment: Great feedback - thanks! If you'd like to contribute, the github repo is https://github.com/ssantner/sp500_time_machine/. Let me know your username and I'll add you as a collaborator.

Comment: I was just answering the mandatory pair of questions for any code review: (1) Is it correct? (2) Is it maintainable? (that is, is it ready to be merged down to `main` where others will interact with it?) My answers were "yes" and "yes".